# How can I set a RadioButton to invoke an action, like a Button can?

Tags: dynamic, evaluation, gui-construction

In Mathematica one can create a Button which, when clicked, invokes an action. For example...

```
action[dog_] := take dog for a walk;

Button["Click here to take fido for a walk",action[fido]];
```

...will call the action `action[fido]` when the button is clicked.
However, I cannot seem to find how to similarly invoke an action when a RadioButton has been called. For example...

```
action[dog_] := take dog for a walk;

RadioButton[dog,action[fido]]
```

...will set the value of dog to `action[fido]`, not simply call the action `action[fido]` like the button does. Is there a way to invoke an action when a RadioButton is clicked?

Comment: Is my answer the answer?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if it is what you are after:

```
action[dog_] := Print@StringForm["take dog no.`` for a walk", dog];

RadioButtonBar[Dynamic[dog, (dog = #; action[dog]) &], {1, 2, 3}]
```